# Remove certain characters in a text file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, scripting

I have a text file; its content is like below.

```
$ cat file.txt
[] [1]foo1 bar1
[] [2]foo2 bar2
[] [35]foo3 bar3
[] [445]foo4 bar4
[] [87898]foo5 bar5
```

I can successfully remove the first column using awk, but I'm unable to remove [num] characters as it is associated with the string.

I'm trying to get a output like below

```
$ cat file.txt
foo1 bar1 
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
foo4 bar4
foo5 bar5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/.*]//' file.txt | tr -s ' '
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
foo4 bar4
foo5 bar5
```

The `sed` removes everything on the line up to (and including) the final `]`, and the `tr` compresses multiple consecutive spaces into single spaces.

Alternatively, using only `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/.*]//' -e 's/  */ /g' file.txt
```

With the given input data, this produces the same output as the first pipeline.

This `sed` first does `s/.*]//` which deletes everything up to the `]` (inclusive). The second expression matches `␣␣*`, i.e. a space followed by zero or more spaces, and replaces these with a single space. The second expression is applied across the whole line and has the same effect as `tr -s ' '`, i.e. it compresses multiple consecutive spaces into single spaces.

---

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '[][:blank:]]*' '{ print $3,$4 }' file.txt
```

Here, we use `]` or spaces or tabs as field separators (multiples of these may separate two column, which is why we use `*` after the `[...]`).  Given those separators, the wanted data is available in fields 3 and 4 on each line.

---

After the data in the question was edited to remove some spaces between the last two columns, the following will also do the job:

```
cut -d ']' -f 3 file.txt
```

alternatively just

```
sed 's/.*]//' file.txt
```

or

```
awk -F ']' '{ print $3 }' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks again. I think in awk, we're missing [ before [:. After adding that it works fine. Other methods also working great. If possible could you please explain me the 2nd sed method? Thanks.

Comment: @smc There is no `[` missing. The `[...]` contains `]` and `[[:blank:]]`. I will add an explanation of the second `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`

```
$ sed -e 's/.*]//g' file
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
foo4 bar4
foo5 bar5
```

You can use `awk

```
$ awk -F'.*]' '{print $2}' file
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
foo4 bar4
foo5 bar5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{$2=substr($2,index($2,"]")+1);print $2,$3}' file
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
foo4 bar4
foo5 bar5
```

The second parameter `$2` is truncated using `substr` from the first `]` found. The parameters 2 and 3 are then printed.

Answer (score 0):

With cut

```
cut -d ] -f3 file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk proposal

```
awk '{gsub(/\[.+foo|\]/,"foo")}1' file
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
foo4 bar4
foo5 bar5
```